# split rows behalf of specific cells value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split rows behalf of cell value (A2). I need 3 separate rows and with 3 different name, rest columns value will be same and hours divided by 3 if cell value (A2) has 2 name then hours will be divided by 2. please suggest how to code in vba

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

This base code will get you there, you'll have to modify it for your range.  It uses the `Split()` function to split the cell into an array and then cycles through the array adding a new row with the information, then deletes the original row.

I would encourage you to do a couple of web searches and find some examples of vba code to help you understand what is going on and what you will need to adjust in this code to make it fit your specific application.

```
Sub Cells2Rows()
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim tStr As String
    Dim tCompany As String
    Dim tDesignation As String
    Dim arrNames() As String
    Dim tMeetings As Double
    Dim i As Long
        Set xlCell = Range("A2")
        tStr = xlCell
        tCompany = xlCell.Offset(0, 1)
        tDesignation = xlCell.Offset(0, 2)
        tMeetings = xlCell.Offset(0, 3)
        arrNames = Split(tStr, Chr(10))
        For i = LBound(arrNames) To UBound(arrNames)
            Debug.Print arrNames(i)
            xlCell.EntireRow.Insert
            xlCell.Offset(-1, 0) = arrNames(i)
            xlCell.Offset(-1, 1) = tCompany
            xlCell.Offset(-1, 2) = tDesignation
            xlCell.Offset(-1, 3) = tMeetings / (UBound(arrNames) + 1)
        Next i
        xlCell.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```